# Moving text-area instead of resizing text

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

**My situation:**
[image]

I have an image and some text besides it, but when I resize the window (as in a mobile view)
I don't want the text to resize as usual,
**What I don't want:**
[image]

I want the browser/device to deside when moving the block below the image.
**What I want:**
[image]

And as I don't know how long the title and description are going to be (as it is a profile), I can't work with media queries or widths.

I tried

So, what would be the most effective way to approuch this?

Comment: can you show us your html?

Comment: Stick the text into a `span` and float it.

Comment: if the title shell be in one line you can add some: `white-space: nowrap` css style and then around the title and the paragraph a span which floats... if we could see your html and css, it would be easier to help

Comment: @MelanciaUK The point is, these are 2 seperate text blocks, the title as well as the description. So if I put the text into a span and let it float, it gives me the same effect as display:inline-block. with that, they will float besides each other. which is not what I wish for

Comment: When I said `the text` I meant the whole thing, including the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to rely on JS, you need to set some 'rough' CSS values to attempt this behaviour, note that I've used a `div` to replicate an `img` in this case.

That said, its far from perfect due to the reliance on approximate % values for calculations. Some JS would definitely aid accuracy.

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZP7r/)

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <img/>
    <div class='content'>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
img, .content{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.content{
    max-width:60%; /* Width should accommodate img */
    min-width:200px; /* minimum width before breaking to new line */
}
```